Noether's theorem: action invariance vs lagrangian invariance
While trying to better understand Noether's theorem, I kept coming across three different formulations of it that seem to be distinct from each other. I'll be focusing on classical field theory in flat spacetime $\mathbb{R}^n$.
The first formulation, which appears to be the standard one, focuses on local invariance of the action. It says that if the action integral over arbitrary domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is invariant under an infinitesimal transformation, then for fields satisfying the equations of motion there is a locally conserved current given by:
$$J^\nu=T^\nu_{\ \ \mu}X^\mu+\frac {\partial \mathcal{L}} {\partial(\partial_\nu\phi^\mu)}\Psi^\mu,$$
where $X^\mu,\Psi^\mu$ are the total derivatives of the coordinates/fields with respect to the continuous transformation parameter and $T^\nu_{\ \ \mu}$ is the stress-energy tensor.
The second formulation differs slightly from the first and focuses on global invariance of the action. It requires only the action defined over all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be invariant but imposes the condition that the fields vanish sufficiently quickly at infinity. In this case there is a globally conserved quantity given by the integral of $J^0$ above over $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.
The third formulation appears in a lot of QFT texts and focuses on invariance of the Lagrangian (density) and on Lagrangians with no explicit dependence on the coordinates. It says that if an infinitesimal transformation changes a Lagrangian only up to a total derivative:
$$\mathcal{L}'=\mathcal{L} +\partial_\mu F^\mu,$$
then for fields satisfying the EOM there exists a locally conserved current:
$$\tilde J^\nu = \frac {\partial \mathcal{L}} {\partial(\partial_\nu\phi^\mu)}\Psi^\mu-F^\nu.$$
My problem is mainly with the connection between the third formulation and the other two. Both the first and the third result in conserved currents, both called Noether currents, but they appear to be different quantities that are conserved under different conditions. From comparing the expressions, they seem to represent the same current only for strictly internal transformations and only when the Lagrangian is strictly invariant, not just up to a total derivative.
This is also the conclusion when comparing the conditions for the formulations. If a transformation changes the Lagrangian by a total derivative $\partial_\mu F^\mu$ which isn't identically zero, then the action integral defined over arbitrary bounded domains will not be invariant to first order under the transformation, since there will be a first order term proportional to the boundary integral of $F^\mu$.
Furthermore, the third formulation implies the conditions of the second formulation hold (assuming the fields vanish at infinity), but they also don't seem to be equivalent since the second formulation only implies a global conserved quantity while the first implies a locally conserved current. My questions are therefore as follows:

Are the conditions of the second and third formulations equivalent? i.e. is there an infinitesimal transformation which keeps the action over $\mathbb{R}^n$ invariant but under which the Lagrangian's transformation cannot be expressed as an addition of a total derivative?

Can the first and third formulations be unified to be aspects of a single theorem, resulting in the same type of conserved current, or are they truly distinct statements dealing with different types of symmetries?



You correctly note at first that the first two formulations are based on invariance of the action $S$, which is a weaker condition that invariance of the Lagrange density $\mathcal{L}$.  In fact, if "the fields vanish sufficiently quickly at infinity," invariance of $S$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{L}$ changing only by a total derivative.
